# How to find mean using pandas for specific class in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there's a straightforward way to only find the mean for a specific class in a dataframe. The file I'm using is for classifying letters so it looks something like this:

```
    class     feature 1    feature 2    feature 3   feature 4 
0   A         2            3            4           1
1   A         3            1            1           0
2   B         6            7            8           8
```

Is there a simple way I can only find the mean for "A" for each feature?

Comment: df[df['class'] == 'A'].mean()?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the mean for the rows in the `class` column with value `A`

```
df[df['class']=='A'].groupby('class')[list(df)[1:]].mean()
```

Output

```
         feature 1  feature 2  feature 3  feature 4
feature                                                   
A              2.5        2.0        2.5        0.5
```

This will give the `mean` for the 4 `feature n` columns.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, `groupby` is 15% faster than the selection-based approach proposed in the comments (`df[df['class'] == 'A'].mean()`):

```
df.groupby('class').mean().loc['A']
#feature 1    2.5
#feature 2    2.0
#feature 3    2.5
#feature 4    0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `mean` with `level`

```
df.set_index('class').mean(level=0).loc[['A']]
Out[431]: 
       feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4
class                                        
A           2.5       2.0       2.5       0.5
```